# Why was the indexed for loop removed in Kotlin?

Tags: for-loop, kotlin

I still think "traditional" way of using the `for` loop is very powerful with full control of the index. Why was it removed in Kotlin?

What should I do in Kotlin with the following java code?

```
for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
   for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
   ....
```

Comment: Probably because they could provide several alternative ways that didn't require you to read the index of the collection you're iterating. If you need to loop until an arbitrary number, you can always use a range in a for loop or just a while loop instead.

Comment: What's wrong with `(0..collection.size - 1).forEach`? It increments the index for you, and you can mutate elements with `collection[it] = blah`.

Comment: Or you can use: `for (i in 0 .. (n - 1))`

Comment: One thing I liked about traditional loops was that I could end the loop on any arbitrary boolean condition. Not sure how to do that in Kotlin without resorting to while loops.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In Kotlin you can use this syntax:

```
for (a in 1..10) print("$a ")              // >>> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

for (a in 10 downTo 1 step 2) print("$a ") // >>> 10 8 6 4 2
```

As for "why was the indexed loop removed" – scroll down for [@yole's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45147481/7637657).

*For more info: [Ranges](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html#ranges) & [Loops](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#for-loops)*

Comment: I understand it, but is there any documentation that explains the second loop syntax? I tried learning kotlin before, but I got fed up because the documentation didn't seem very good.

Comment: Hi，the OP ask **why** the traditional loop is removed in Kotlin rather than **how**?

Comment: @Alex Follow the "ranges" link in my answer. If you want to learn Kotlin, I would suggest to read "Kotlin in Action" book.

Comment: @holi-java Well, only guys from Kotlin team can answer **why**.

Comment: @Alex I'd like to say master java over any books. you just need to read https://kotlinlang.org only.

Comment: For anyone here like I was, the `for(i in 0..n)` and `for(i in 0 until n)` syntax translates directly to a for loop without any range creation overhead. `(0..n).forEach` and any more complex ranges (e.g. `step`) in a for loop however create an iterator.

Comment: How can I arbitrarily change the index to any value I want during the iteration?

Answer (score 26):

It was not "removed". The design of a new language doesn't start with the feature set of any existing language; we start with a language that has no features, and start adding features which are necessary to express certain behavior in a nice and idiomatic way. Up until now, we aren't aware of any behavior for which a C-style 'for' loop would be the nicest and most idiomatic way to express it.

Comment: C-style 'for' loop has a simple consistent syntax though, that can be used for anything. With Kotlin you forked this simple concept into many different ones. It's one of the very few things I don't like about the language.

Comment: @Vitaly I'd say it's the opposite. Java has two different loop syntaxes, and Kotlin has just one, plus a single additional concept of a range which has additional uses outside of loops.

Comment: Simple, counter based, C style for loops can be compiled, without optimization, into quite efficient machine code. Kotlin style loops seems to be quite complex behind the scenes. What ensures that on all platforms and on all compilers these loops will be well optimized?

Comment: @Endre it looks like ranges as part of loops are actually compiled to optimized byte code (at least for Kotlin 1.5.0 with JVM as target), even though the IDE will claim that operators such as `..` or `until` create an `IntRange` object. Though be careful when calling functions which accept ranges, such as `String.substring(IntRange)`, because at the moment they seem to create `IntRange` objects, which is pretty wasteful compared to calling `String.substring(Int, Int)`.

Comment: Also, what if you want to iterate using floating-point variable? Good luck with that. I had to re-invent the traditional for-loop because kotlin ranges and progressions do not include floating point types. I think removing the traditional for without really thinking about descent replacements for all usecases was an overreach from the kotlin team.

Comment: Please add indexed for loop to Kotlin.

Comment: One thing the indexed for loop is good for: Processing sequences where you skip N further elements, for whatever reason. For instance:  Parsing CLI arguments. With indexed for loop, you can just `i += N`.

Comment: With C-style 'for' loop it is possible to iterate over just Comparable types without need of implementing an iterator: `for (val t = ZonedDateTime.now(); t > thePast; t.minusHours(123))`. Do-While do the thing but it is requires more lines, needs mutable cursor variable and doesn't looks idiomatic at all.

Answer (score 10):

Another useful way of retaining those indexes white iterating something (an [Iterable](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-iterable/index.html), that is), is to use the [`withIndex()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/with-index.html) method. For example:

```java
for((i, element) in myIterable.withIndex()){
    //do something with your element and the now known index, i
}
```

This I noticed achieves the same as what suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45147209/3908170) answer, but I think it is better if we use the already built-in method Iterables have for such situations instead of implementing them again. This we could say is also similar to the [`forEachIndexed{}`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each-indexed.html) lambda:

```java
myIterable.forEachIndexed{i, element ->
    //do something here as well
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I think the reason why they made it that way, ("not removed") is because, they wanted to make Kotlin more expressive.

For example, in java we can create a for-loop like this:

```
for(int x = 1; x <= 10; x++) {
   System.out.print(x);
}
```

All you are trying to do is that, you want to print out values **from 1 to 10**, that's it. So Kotlin decided to translate your words into code and remove unneeded verbosity.

```
for (x in 1..10) print("$x")
```

Comment: Your two snippets will print different values in Java in Kotlin. Kotlin example is incorrect

Comment: Actually, based on the requirements (print values from 1 to 10), the Java code is the incorrect one as it will only print from 1 to 9. One more reason to prefer the Kotlin syntax

Answer (score 4):

It wasn't removed. It's just different syntax for it.
The equivalent of Java code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
   for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
```

Would be written in Kotlin this way:

```
val n = 10
for (i in 0..n-2) {
    for (j in i+1..n-1) {
        println("I'm low level for loop! I just look more friendly.")
    }
}
```

Kotlin uses [Ranges](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html) to define loops' iterators for the sake of code brevity.

Comment: `for (i in 0..n-2) {` it is worth noting that you don't need to manipulate the end index if you use `for(i in 0 until n-1)`

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to use a traditional `for` loop in Kotlin, because you can using Kotlin lambdas to makes your code more **expressive** and **readable**. for example:

```
arrayOf(1, 2, 3).forEachIndexed { index, item -> /**TODO**/}
```

Kotlin only supports [for-each](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#for-loops) loop, 
The [for-each](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#for-loops) loop accept any `Iterable`s/ `Array`s/ the type has an `iterator` operator.

**IF** you want to back to use the [for-each](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#for-loops) loop expression, you can write the code as below, and you can see that [for-each](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#for-loops) loop will take more code than lamda, this is why stream api & functional interface were introduced in [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8):

```
val array  = arrayOf(1, 2, 3)

for(index in array.indices){
  val item = array[index]
  // todo
}
```

**IF** you need to back to the traditional `for` loop you can using `repeat` instead, for example:

```
repeat(5){index-> /**TODO**/}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this if you want to get the index and the value at the same time.

```
for ((index, value) in array.withIndex()) {
    println("the element at $index is $value")
}
```

This is pretty simple.

Source: [Kotlin Official Documentation - Control Flow](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html)

Answer (score 1):

You may create own function to realize "traditional loop with full control of the index".
Or non-traditional.
For example, hybrid `forEachIndexed()`, `with()`, `count()` with index 1 to count.

```
inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.forWithIndexed1(action: T.(index: Int) -> Unit): Int {
    var index = 0
    for (item in this) item.action(++index)
    return index
}
```

Comment: Good approach on using extension functions. Although I must say this method is already implemented by default on iterables. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50183469/3908170) for the details.

Answer (score 1):

It does not make any sense because at times you want to have more custom loops with custom steps and that structure kind of removes that from the logic

```js
var array = ["-m", "/test/app", "-w", "us"];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 2) {
    console.log("option =" + array[i]);
    console.log("value =" + array[i+1])
}
```

With the current kotlin loop, we lose some of the simplicity that was there.

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin is trying to enforce fluent iteration, which covers the vast majority of looping constructs. However, I needed a traditional for loop (like java) with an immediately terminating state scope, exit condition that evaluates before loop-body execution, and a post-execution operation (my use case was complicated: I needed to repeat using a dynamic exit condition based on a compression routine and powers of 2). I came up with these general functions:

```
fun <S> forloop(state: S, condition: (s: S) -> Boolean, postExecution: (s: S) -> Unit, block: (s: S) -> Unit) {
  while (condition(state)) {
    block(state)
    postExecution(state)
  }
}

data class SingleIndex(var i: Int)
fun forloop(i: Int, condition: (s: SingleIndex) -> Boolean, postExecution: (s: SingleIndex) -> Unit, block: (s: SingleIndex) -> Unit) {
  forloop(SingleIndex(i), condition, postExecution, block)
}
```

Examples [here](https://pl.kotl.in/31u-T1FY8):

```
fun main() {
    forloop(0, {it.i < 10}, {++it.i}) {
        println("forloop test: i=${it.i}")
    }

    data class State(var i: Int, var j: Int)
    forloop(State(0, 1), {it.i < 10}, {++it.i; it.j += it.i}) {
        println("forloop test: i=${it.i}, j=${it.j}")
    }
}
```

Although, in compliance with the language philosophy, you should only use this in rare circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

```
generateSequence(0) { it + 2 }.takeWhile { it < array.length }.forEach {
    // Do something useful
}
```

Comment: How is this the replacement for the code in the question?

Comment: Actually this is the answer that I was looking for. It lets you do anything a java for loop would do, and I need to use this kind of stuff a lot. I would even argue that this is the best answer in the thread (although it could benefit from a description).

Answer (score 0):

For this exact case the following double loop can be used:

```
for (i in 0 until n) {
        for (j in (i + 1) .. n) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i in generateSequence(0) { it + 2 }.takeWhile { it < array.length }) {
    // do something useful
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please avoid posting code only answers. At the very least, add an explanation of the context and what it does.

Answer (score -1):

**Why?**
"Traditional" loop is a cause of "index out of bounds" exception unlike
the loop on collection's items.

Comment: hmmm, somehow I think it give me more control over the flow.

Comment: That's not the reason. you can easily get IOOB exception using loop with ranges

Comment: Don't use the range loop when the collection iteration is possible.

Comment: Base on your answer I started to like much more Kotlin reasoning. :)